How to setup tabulator.js project for debugging
I want to debug an issue in tabulator.js tool, but I don't know how to setup correctly for debugging. I want to try fix this bug that someone posted in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/krishnasai057/pxqrjd2b/
Here is my setup:
I have a simple flask app to serve up content
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

with this dir structure
 tree -L 2
.
├── app.py
├── static
│   ├── main.js
│   └── tabulator   << this is the git clone dir
└── templates
    └── index.html

and the index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@6.2.0/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/static/tabulator/dist/js/tabulator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example-table"></div>
<script>
    var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        data: tableData,
        layout: "fitData",
        columns: [
            { title: "id", field: "id", width: 150 },
            { title: "parentId", field: "parentId" },
        ],
        dataTree: true,
        dataTreeStartExpanded: false,
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>

All this works where the source.map correctly points out the non minified code that it loads from  <script src="/static/tabulator/dist/js/tabulator.js"></script> say for example I want to edit the code in /static/tabulator/src/js/modules/DataTree/DataTree.js,  how does the dist/js/tabulartor.js pick up the data.
I have seen jsx compiler do similar thing for every edit it recreates the dist folder.  So what am i missing ?
